# FireDac set up a Persistent Connection using a ini file

Tags: mysql, delphi, c++builder, firedac

I would like to set up a persistent connection with MySQL database using an ini file with FireDac.
I have a ini file like this named a.ini

```
[fConn]
Database=atom
User_Name=ud...
Password=#####
Server=192.168.20.20
DriverID=MySQL
```

in the DataModuleCreate a code like this

```
   FDManager.ConnectionDefFileAutoLoad := false;
   FDManager.ConnectionDefFileName := 'a.ini';
   FDManager.LoadConnectionDefFile;
   connection1.ConnectionName := 'fConn';
```

but i receive a database error that the Access denied for ud...@localhost with password YES I know that localhost is added when the server doesn't find a valid user.

Manuals examples give us the opportunity to write the ini file but i only want to read it.
whats wrong in my code? what i missed?
thank you in advice.

Comment: directly set paramter to TConnection , https://github.com/ImageProcessingFMX/MySQL_CrossPlatformAdmin

Answer (score 0):

Due to the comment above i wrote this peace of code, hope it'll be helpful.

```
var
  sr: TStreamReader;
begin


  sr := tStreamReader.Create(TFileStream.Create('at.ini',fmOpenRead),TEncoding.UTF8);

  with connection1 do begin
    Close;
    with Params do begin
       Clear;
       while not sr.EndOfStream do begin
         add(sr.ReadLine);
       end;
    end;
  end;
sr.free;
end
```

it works for me. Thank's

Comment: That is not the best way you read an `.ini` file.  Look at `T(Mem)IniFile` and its `ReadSectionValues()` method, eg: `ini := TMemIniFile.Create('at.ini',TEncoding.UTF8); with Connection1 do begin Close; Params.Clear; ini.ReadSectionValues('fConn', Params); end; ini.Free;`

Comment: In any case, all of the `Params` values can be set in code without using an `.ini` file at all.